# Detect Specific Intent through DialogFlow v2 API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have multiple intents setup, I want to check if specific Intent matches with input audio file /audio stream.

For example I have following Intents:
Intent1, Intent2, Intent3...

I receive an audio file and I want to check if it matches Intent1 or not.

Comment: Well, that sounds like what Dialogflow does. Is it not doing this? You may wish to update your question to show the code you're using and better illustrate what is or isn't happening.

Comment: I see that @Niktar has edited the tags as well. You may wish to clarify if you're actually trying to do this for Android or, if not, what environment you're trying to do this with.